# Нужно вызвать ошибку JAVA

Tags: java

Напишите строку вызова этой функции с такой строкой-паролем, чтобы возникло какое-нибудь исключение.

Корректным по форме, но не по содержанию является, например, ответ

```
boolean correct = checkPass("12345678");
```

функиця:

```java
boolean checkPass(String password){
   if (password.length() > 2 && password.charAt(4) != ' ') return true;
   else return false;
}
```

Comment: Какой этой функции?

Comment: да, все добавил

Comment: `checkPass("123");`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не, он походу имеет ввиду, чтобы crash именно произошёл

Comment: Глупая идея, но попробуй длинющюю строку туда вписать

Comment: А вообще блин, просто генератор строк (с абсолютно всеми символами) возьми из интернета и генерируй с разными длинами минут 5, и всё

Comment: С тремя символами как раз краш по выходу за пределы массива будет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
checkPass(null);
```

Вызовет `NullPointerException`

Или по совету @ЮрийСПб:

```
checkPass("123");
```

Вызовет `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`